# how do I print only the last result in a 'for' loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I print only the final result of a 'for' loop? For example, here I want the print only the last result (and not all of them):

```
A=[1,2.5,3,4,5]
a=A[1::2]
b=A[0::2]
c=b[0]

for num in b:
    c=c*num  
    print sum(a),c
```

Comment: Put the print outside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mattias said, just put the print outside the for loop, like this

```
A=[1,2.5,3,4,5]
a=A[1::2]
b=A[0::2]
c=b[0]

for num in b:
    c=c*num  

print sum(a),c  #notice that is now outside the loop
```

at the end of the loop `c` would have it latest calculate value from the for-loop which then you can print it or do whatever you want with it

Answer (score 0):

Try using `for i in range(len(b)):` and then `if i == len(b)-1: execute code` instead of your for loop.

Comment: Thank you!  You've helped me a lot:)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the for/else pattern:

```
a = 1
for i in xrange(1, 10):
    a *= i
else:
    print a
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable:

```
A=[1,2.5,3,4,5]
a=A[1::2]
b=A[0::2]
c=b[0]

for num in b:
    c=c*num  
    l=sum(a),c
print(l)
```